# JPA + Criteria + date handling

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

```
select * from xyz where  to_char(sdateAndTime,'DD-MM-YYYY')=(select max( to_char(sdateAndTime,'DD-MM-YYYY')) as dt from xyz))

sdateAndTime is timestamp field in oracle db. i am interested to fetch record for that given date and not in hh:mm:ss:zzzz AM/PM.

Trying to build criteria for it but :(

CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<XYZ> criteria = builder.createQuery(XYZ.class);
Root<XYZ> root = criteria.from(XYZ.class);
criteria.select(root);
Subquery<XYZ> sub = criteria.subquery(XYZ.class);
Root subRoot = sub.from(XYZ.class);
sub.select(builder.max(subRoot.get("sdateAndTime")));
criteria.select(root).where(builder.in(root.get("sdateAndTime")).value(sub);
entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```

i was able to reach extract max of dd:hh:mm:ss however unable to get equivalent of to_char(sdateAndTime,'DD-MM-YYYY')

inputs would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the question? Are you getting an error message or are you not getting the correct output? If you're not getting the correct output, what are you getting and what do you expect? Also, please fix the formatting on your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function() API to call a database function, such as "TO_CHAR".

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Special_Operations

Answer (score 1):

Thanks James for your inputs...!!

I modified above criteria query with below changes to get desired result.

```
Subquery<String> sub = criteria.subquery(String.class);
        Root subRoot = sub.from(XYZ.class);
        sub.select(builder.substring(builder.greatest(builder.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, subRoot.get("sdateAndTime"))),0,10));
        criteria.select(root).where(
                builder.equal(builder.substring(builder.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, root.get("sdateAndTime")),0,10),sub)
```

Note: I was unable to pass DD-MM-YYYY as parameter, thereby as workaround used substring.
Better soln would be appreciated.